# How to show data from django models whose boolean field is true?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

```
verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to show only that objects in frontend whose verified field is true in Django models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways

1. you can handle this on your views

in `views.py`

```
modelList = modelname.objects.filter(verified=True)
```

2. also you can handle it on HTML

in `views.py`

```
modelList = modelname.objects.all()
```

in `html`

```
{% for models in modelList %}

    {% if models.verified == True %}
       # Your Code
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please *don't*, it makes the views less efficient: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/filtering-in-the-template.html especially since the Django template engine is not that fast.

Comment: I said there are many ways And you are right 
A filter can also be used, but I said one of the methods

Comment: but it is not a good method in general. The bandwidth used to communicate between the database and the Django/Python layer can be gigantic compared to the rendered items, and Django's render engine is not fast at all. Usually if there are two methods, and one method is more *pareto effective* than another one, then usually it makes no sense to discuss the other one. An answer is valid if it at least has an objective parameter for which it is better than another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You filter the items with:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(verified=True)
```

with `MyModel` the model that contains the `verified` field.

Answer (score 0):

you have to ways to achive that that either it with your views or html

first views
you can filter your model to return only object which is verfied like this

```
name = modelname.objects.filter(verified=True)
```

second way
or you can pass in html while you are requesting all object of that field in views
in views

```
name = modelname.objects.all()
```

then in html while fetching data

```
{% for name in models %}
{% if name.verified == True %}
then pass the object which are verified 
{% else %}
pass another data
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

i hope now you got my point tell me if you got any error while implementing any of these code