# How to fetch a boolean value from models for a specific user in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have an extended user model and I want to check it to see if the logged-in user has `completed_application` as per the model:

Models.py:

```
class Completed(models.Model):
class Meta:  
    verbose_name_plural = 'Completed Application'
user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
completed_application = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.completed_application}'
```

Views.py:

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    if Completed.objects.get(completed_application = True):
        completed = True
    else:
        completed = False
        
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard', 'completed' : completed})
```

HTML:

```
{% if completed %}
<!-- You already completed an application! -->
<h1> Already completed </h1>
{% else %}
<!-- Show the application form -->
<h1> Render model form here </h1>
{% endif %}
```

The code above is not working for me as it returns True every time. I read quite a few posts on here but they don't seem to be user specific such as: [How to show data from django models whose boolean field is true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68940721/how-to-show-data-from-django-models-whose-boolean-field-is-true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the problem is you have to change your queryset

```
Completed.objects.get(completed_application ...etc
```

To:

```
Completed.objects.filter(completed_application=True,user=request.user).exists()
```

Comment: That has fixed the problem, thank you so much!